# Script sharp # with web workers

Tags: javascript, web-worker, script#

How can I use web workers from Script sharp?

Web workers need a source file, that will not compile in Script sharp because it is not a class, it's just code.

Ideas? Nikhilk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest stuff that is there on github, you can create an internal static class with just a static ctor, and mark the class as [ScriptModule] - it will generate top-level code. Think of this as main() for any particular script file.

Hope that helps.